# Python - Inner Class Not Found

Tags: python, django

(Sorry I'm new to Python)

I'm running a python django script as follows:

`python3 manage.py test`

---

```
class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    help = 'Help Test'
    def handle(self, **options):
        gs = self.create_goalscorer(1,"Headed")

    class GoalScorerX(object):
        id = 0
        goal_type = ""
        #Constructor
        def __init__(self, id, goal_type):
           self.id= id
           self.goal_type = goal_type

    def create_goalscorer(self,id,goal_type):
        gs = GoalScorerX(id, goal_type)
        return gs
```

But I get the error that it can't be found?

```
    gs = GoalScorerX(id, goal_type)
NameError: name 'GoalScorerX' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inner classes are very rarely useful in Python. Certainly here there is nothing to be gained by making GoalScorerX an inner class. Move it outside; also note that there is no restriction in Python in the number of classes in a file, so it's fine to have them both as top-level classes.

(Note, you *could* fix this by referring to the inner class as Command.GoalScorerX - but don't do that.)

Comment: Is it okay to use `self`? `gs = self.GoalScorerX(id, goal_type)`

Comment: It might work, but it's semantically wrong; GoalScorer is not an attribute of the instance. As I say, you should take that out of the Command class altogether.